# Double くれる?「教えてくれてくれませんか」

Tags: giving-and-receiving

I just came across this on a Japanese forum. Someone asking a question says:

> どなたか教えてくれてくれませんか？

I personally have never seen double くれ. I can see how it'd make sense in a different context though. I found [this weblio entry](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B):

> **くれてくれる**
> [多]＝「くれる（物を与える）」と「くれる（好意的な行為）　・「おじさんが　お金を　くれてくれた」

But do people say it like this?

> 本をくれてくれてありがとう。

Also the line that I encountered didn't seem to be the same case, as it was not about about giving/receiving a physical object. Does it work?

Comment: Sure it's not just a typo?

Comment: This must be just a typo. (BTW we don't usually say お金をくれてくれた or 本をくれてくれてありがとう, either. お金をくれた or 本をくれてありがとう is enough. Your link is from あがつま語実用会話講座, a non-authoritative dialect dictionary)